# Rails: Testing ActiveMailer delivery method settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to test if my `UserMailer` is sending messages to the correct SMTP server specified by the customer (referred in code as a tenant).

Using a `before_action` hook in the user mailer:

```rb
  1 class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  2   before_action :set_user
  3   before_action :set_smtp_settings
```

the code of that hook is:

```rb
191   def set_smtp_settings
192     tenant_email_provider = @user.tenant.email_providers.where(provider_type: 'smtp').take
193     tenant_smtp_settings = (tenant_email_provider&.settings || {}).with_indifferent_access
194     
195     current_settings = (message.delivery_method.settings || {} ).with_indifferent_access
196     new_settings = current_settings.merge(tenant_smtp_settings)
197     
198     raise "No server address to send to" if new_settings[:address].nil?
199     
200     message.delivery_method.settings = new_settings
201   end
```

The unit test is:

```rb
  9   test 'that the settings are according to a mailer' do
 10     expected_settings = email_provider.settings.with_indifferent_access
 11 
 12     message = @mailer.account_activation_confirm
 13     sent_message = message.deliver_now
 14 
 15     actual_settings = sent_message.delivery_method.settings.with_indifferent_access
 16 
 17     intersecting_keys = expected_settings.keys.map(&:to_sym) | actual_settings.keys
 18     assert intersecting_keys.include?(:address)
 19 
 20     intersecting_keys.each do |setting|
 21       expected = expected_settings[setting].to_s
 22       actual = actual_settings[setting].to_s
 23       assert_equal(expected, actual, "smtp value of setting '#{setting}' do not match (#{expected} != #{actual})")
 24     end
```

The result of that test is:

```
Failure:
DeliverSettingsTest#test_that_the_settings_are_according_to_a_mailer [/opt/xxx-web/test/mailers/deliver_settings_test.rb:25]:
smtp value of setting 'address' do not match (mail.hello.com != ).
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1,3 @@
-"mail.hello.com"
+# encoding: US-ASCII
+#    valid: true
+""
```

Furthermore, on line 15 in the unit test, `sent_message.delivery_method.settings.with_indifferent_access` is an empty hash. Whereas in line 200 in the hook, `message.delivery_method.settings` is set.

Adding debugger calls and prints outs as proof:

In the hook:

```rb
   200|     message.delivery_method.settings = new_settings
=> 201|     debugger
   202|     nil
   203|   end
   204| 
   205| end
=>#0    UserMailer#set_smtp_settings at /opt/xxx-web/app/mailers/user_mailer.rb:201
  #1    block {|target=#<UserMailer:0x00000000018998>, value=nil, block=nil|} in make_lambda at /usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-7.0.5.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:400
  # and 53 frames (use `bt' command for all frames)
(ruby) message.delivery_method.settings
{"address"=>"mail.hello.com",                      <----- Populated Hash
 "port"=>25,
 "domain"=>"localhost.localdomain",
 "user_name"=>"prius",
 "password"=>"bunch_tr1k3s!",
 "authentication"=>nil,
 "enable_starttls"=>nil,
 "enable_starttls_auto"=>true,
 "openssl_verify_mode"=>nil,
 "ssl"=>nil,
 "tls"=>nil,
 "open_timeout"=>5,
 "read_timeout"=>5}
(rdbg)
```

in the testing environment

```rb
(rdbg) c    # continue command
[12, 21] in /opt/xxx-web/test/mailers/deliver_settings_test.rb
    12|     message = @mailer.account_activation_confirm
    13|     sent_message = message.deliver_now
    14| 
    15|     actual_settings = sent_message.delivery_method.settings.with_indifferent_access
    16| 
=>  17|     debugger
    18| 
    19|     intersecting_keys = expected_settings.keys.map(&:to_sym) | actual_settings.keys
    20|     assert intersecting_keys.include?(:address)
    21| 
=>#0    block in <class:DeliverSettingsTest> at /opt/xxx-web/test/mailers/deliver_settings_test.rb:17
  #1    block in run (3 levels) at /usr/local/bundle/gems/minitest-5.18.1/lib/minitest/test.rb:94
  # and 24 frames (use `bt' command for all frames)
(ruby) actual_settings
{}                                             <--------- Empty Hash
```

Is the ActiveMailer library or test stub clearing out the delivery_method.settings after sending?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Rails guide, use `after_action` instead of `before_action`

> "Using an `after_action` callback also enables you to override delivery method settings by updating `mail.delivery_method.settings`."
>
> -- https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-callbacks